# Why can't I upload images to Django app running on Ubuntu server?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload images to my Django application running on Ubuntu server. I have everything required, but somehow when I post it, I don't see any images saved. I've checked the Admin, but the field is empty. 
The thing is, I DON'T GET ANY ERROR MESSAGES. The whole process works fine, except that the field remains empty. Let me show you my code first.
models.py

```
class NewEvent(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    img1 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="everyday_img")
    ...
```

forms.py

```
class NewEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    img1 = forms.ImageField(required=False)
...
```

views.py

```
def inputNew(request):
    form = NewEventForm(initial={'authuser':request.user})
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewEventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.authuser = request.user
            instance.img1 = request.FILES.get('img1')
            instance.save()
...
```

And the template for uploading image.

```
<form method="post" class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="everyday-img-input">{{form.img1|as_crispy_field}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've also tried the `chmod` command, and taken care of the permission. There's nothing wrong there. What do you think is the problem? Thank you very much in advance. :) 
+++ I have everything set fine in my settings.py as well. That's why I'm stuck :(

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
...
    path('newevent/', include('newevent.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Do you have your MEDIA ROOT set up in your settings file?

Comment: have configured URL for static files?

Comment: @dfundako Yes. I've edited my post, and I believe everything is fine in my settings.

Comment: @PruthviBarot I'm sorry what do you exactly mean by configuring URL for static files?

Comment: add urls.py. I'll tell if anything missing

Comment: You don't need to handle `instance.img1 = request.FILES.get('img1')` separately since it's already in the form!

Comment: @PruthviBarot I've added the ```urls.py``` file in the root folder. Thanks.

Comment: @AKX I'm sorry but what do you mean by handle separately?

Comment: Exactly what was in the answer provided – don't assign the image manually.

Answer (score 1):

you should do like this into your view function

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewEventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.authuser = request.user
        instance.save()
```

Comment: Well this is exactly what I have in my ```views.py```, except that I have ```instance.img1 = request.FILES.get('img1')``` inside the inner if statement

Comment: Okay so this time the image is saved, but I get 404 error with the image. I believe it's the path error, right?

Comment: Can you find the image in your filesystem ?

Comment: @RyanOh yes maybe, please provide traceback also

Comment: @PruthviBarot Oh actually all I see in the console is ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()```. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: @Taek Yes. I did as PruthviBarot told me to, and now I see the file is saved, as I've checked in the admin. But now I get 404 error :(

Comment: @PruthviBarot Hey I've found the error message. Sorry I'm still new do Django and it's taking while to get through it. ```Using the URLconf defined in <code>mvp.urls</code>``` This is the error message. ```mvp.urls``` is the url file in the root folder.